# Нет четкости PhpStorm Win8

Tags: веб-программирование, ide, phpstorm, windows-8, jetbrains

Установил PhpStorm + WebStorm на windows 8. Как улучшить качество изображения в PhpStorm (на текущий момент шрифты не четкие)? PHPStorm - качество ужасное. WebStorm - отличное качество. Настроил ClearType - ситуация не изменилась. Как улучшить качество отображения PhpStorm?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJiJn.png

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Скрин покажите что ли (залейте на imgur.com).

Comment: [Фото phpstorm](http://imgur.com/X7tSJeR)

@andreycha

Answer (score 1):

Правый клик на значке приложения - Свойства - Совместимость. Ставите галочку "Отключить масштабирование при высоком разрешении экрана". Работает для всех приложений, которые не поддерживают масштабирование.

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете системное масштабирование.

Start > введите "larger" > "Make text and other items larger or smaller"

В этом диалоге у вас, скорее всего, выбрано масштабирование, отличное от 100%.

Далеко не все приложения корректно поддерживают масштабирование. Некоторые приложения разъезжаются в стороны, некоторые замыливаются (по-моему, подобное масштабирование картинки — новая фича в Windows 8). Обратите внимание, что даже иконки на панели задач выглядят не очень аккуратно.

Строго говоря, это недоработка PHPStorm. Можете написать в багтрекер JetBrains, что у приложения проблемы с масштабированием. (Убедитесь, что подобный баг ещё не заведён.)

В качестве временного воркэраунда можете переключить масштабирование на 100%.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Comment: @AlexanderChibilyaev Можете поставить галочку напротив ответа, чтобы принять его.